# How to scrape 'aria-label' with robobrowser

Tags: python, web-scraping, robobrowser

I'm new to web scraping and currently using robobrowser to scrape a webpage.
I'm trying to scrape the value of 'aria-label' under a certain class, but don't know how to do.

Here is my code.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True, parser='html.parser')
browser.open('https://www.scrapingwebsite.com')
links = browser.find_all(class_='searchResult__373c0__1yggB')
for link in links:
    print(link.find(class_='big_braket_class').text)
    problem_part = link.find(class_='subsidiary_class')
    print(problem_part.get('aria-label'))
```

It simply doesn't work. Is there any way to make it work?
Thx

Comment: what does doesn't work mean? Is there an error? Also, can you share the url?

Comment: Please, share the snippet or a sample HTML that you want to scrap, and explain what is the expected result. It is otherwise hard to understand based on the sample code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dump content from robobrowser into bs4. Then with bs4 4.7.1 use :has and :contains to target required items.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#...your code
soup = browser.parsed
data = [(item.select_one('[class*=businessName]').text.replace('\xa0',''), item.select_one('[class*="i-stars"]')['aria-label']) for item in soup.select('li:has(h3:contains("All Results")) ~ li:has([class*=businessName])')]
print(data)
```

Sample of results:

[image]

Comment: Sorry guys, it is my first time using Stack Overflow. Everything is new to me.
Anyway here are some more details.

This is the original URL that I want to scrape: 
https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=Memphis%2C%20TN&sortby=rating&attrs=RestaurantsPriceRange2.3%2CRestaurantsPriceRange2.4

Expected result: 
1. Flight Restaurant & Wine Bar
4.5 ratings
914 reviews
American (new), Wine Bars, Venues & Events Spaces

2.McEwan's Memphis
4.5 rating
etc...

Comment: your code works, but it returns a whole list of 'aria-label's for all restaurants
i.e. [4.5 star rating, 4.5 star rating, 4.0 star rating, 4.0 star rating etc....]
I want them separated and shown one each for each restaurant. Can you help?

Comment: yup
https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=Memphis%2C%20TN&sortby=rating&attrs=RestaurantsPriceRange2.3%2CRestaurantsPriceRange2.4

Comment: Awesome! Kudos for you!

Comment: can you help me on this further? I got stuck again... plz see the follow-up question below.